# Numeric collation sorts by digits instead of value- postgres

Tags: postgresql, collation, sorting, international-components-unicode

I have a table of users with ids in the following form `user123@domain.com`.
When searching and sorting the users, I need `user1@domian.com` to be before `user14@domain.com` but since 4 is “smaller” than @ it sorts the other way around.

After looking around I came across the following collation:

```
CREATE COLLATION numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en-u-kn-true');
```

Which fixed the problem, but caused another one, users with numbers that started with 2 appeared after users that started with 1

For example, `user19@domain.com` came before `user2@domain.com`

From the docs, it says that `kn-true` and looks at the number’s value but it looks like it only compares the digits.

I'm using Postgres 11.6.  I have two servers: one on Windows (local) and a remote one on Linux.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you using a very old version of the ICU library that does not support this syntax?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How can I check the ICU version and some docs about when the feature was added?

Comment: How to check the version if installed software depends on your operating system, which you didn't disclose. For old versions, it would be `locale = 'en@colNumeric=true'`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a potential alternative solution to your problem. Rather than creating a collation, you could do following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UuboD4fI)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  e_id  INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  email TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Then populate it (out of order - i.e. we're not relying on `INSERT` order or physical order on disk of either the heap or the `PRIMARY KEY`):

```
INSERT INTO test (email) VALUES
('user34@x.com'),   
('user123@x.com'),  -- Note: deliberately out of order!
('user1@x.com'),
('user23343@x.com'),
('user3@x.com'),
('user7@x.com'),
('user21@x.com'),
('user223@x.com'),
```

and then we check sorting by email (`SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY email;`) - result (out of order both by email and `PRIMARY KEY`):

```
test
(2,user123@x.com)
(3,user1@x.com)
(7,user21@x.com)
...
... snipped for brevity - see fiddle
...
```

So, now we combine a couple of functions to obtain the desired sort order. We will use the [`SUBSTRING()`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) (with a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)<sup>1</sup> - also see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html)) and the [`SPLIT_PART()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-split_part/) ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html)), then cast the result of this function combination to an `INTEGER` using PostgreSQL's double-colon ([`::`](https://learnsql.com/blog/double-colon-operator-postgresql/)) cast operator and sort by that `INTEGER`.

<sub>1. An excellent introduction to regexes</sub>

We can see what's happening in the following query:

```
SELECT 
  e_id, email,
  SUBSTRING(email FROM '\d.*'),
  SPLIT_PART(SUBSTRING(email FROM '\d.*'), '@', 1)::INT AS num_split_part
FROM test
ORDER BY num_split_part;
```

Result:

```
e_id    email            substring  num_split_part
   3  user1@x.com          1@x.com               1
   5  user3@x.com          3@x.com               3
   6  user7@x.com          7@x.com               7
   7  user21@x.com        21@x.com              21
   1  user34@x.com        34@x.com              34
   2  user123@x.com      123@x.com             123
   8  user223@x.com      223@x.com             223
   4  user23343@x.com  23343@x.com           23343
```

Et voilà - the emails are sorted in the desired order!

We can add an enhancement to this by using an [`expression index`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-index-on-expression/) (aka a functional index - see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html)) as follows.

First, we'll take a look at the `EXPLAIN` plan without the index:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)
SELECT 
  email
FROM test
ORDER BY num_split_part;
```

Result:

```
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=10000000104.05..10000000107.22 rows=1270 width=72) (actual time=0.048..0.049 rows=8 loops=1)
  Output: e_id, email, ("substring"(email, '\d.*'::text)), ((split_part("substring"(email, '\d.*'::text), '@'::text, 1))::integer)
  Sort Key: ((split_part("substring"(test.email, '\d.*'::text), '@'::text, 1))::integer)
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Seq Scan on public.test  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000038.58 rows=1270 width=72) (actual time=0.015..0.034 rows=8 loops=1)
        Output: e_id, email, "substring"(email, '\d.*'::text), (split_part("substring"(email, '\d.*'::text), '@'::text, 1))::integer
        Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.042 ms
Execution Time: 0.074 ms
```

Note the `Seq Scan on public.test` which means that every record of the table has to be traversed before a result can be derived - **even though** I did `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`.

A brief diversion about `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`.

- This doesn't actually disable sequential table scans, it just makes them very expensive - see discussion below.
- Do not do this on production systems, or at least don't do it globally. You could, if and only if you fully understand any consequences, do it on a case-by-case, query-by-query basis, but it's not to be recommended. Today's query hints are tomorrow's bugs - use with caution.

The reason I'm doing it here is to force the optimiser to choose the index over a sequential scan. Without enable_seqscan = OFF, the very small sample tables here would cause the optimiser to automatically choose a sequential scan. With a large number of records on a production system, this should not be a problem.

From the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html):

> enable_seqscan (boolean)
>
> Enables or disables the query planner's use of sequential scan plan
> types. It is impossible to suppress sequential scans entirely, but
> turning this variable off discourages the planner from using one if
> there are other methods available. The default is on.

We create the expression index as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX func_idx ON test 
((
  SPLIT_PART(SUBSTRING(email FROM '\d.*'), '@', 1)::INT 
));  -- the use of ::INT obliges us to have two opening and closin brackets!
```

and rerun the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` (see the fiddle) and we get this:

```
QUERY PLAN
Index Scan using func_idx on public.test  (cost=0.13..12.35 rows=8 width=72) (actual time=0.037..0.057 rows=8 loops=1)
  Output: e_id, email, "substring"(email, '\d.*'::text), (split_part("substring"(email, '\d.*'::text), '@'::text, 1))::integer
  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1
Planning Time: 0.225 ms
Execution Time: 0.078 ms
```

Now, we have an `Index Scan using func_idx on public.test` which is usually preferable to a `Seq Scan`. Also, note that this plan is 5 lines long, the previous one was 10 - as a rule of thumb, shorter plans are better (= faster queries).

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you are using windows, the problem could be that you are using an old version of the ICU library that does not yet understand the syntax you are using. Try

```
CREATE COLLATION numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colNumeric=true');
```